# Add rotated comment on margin

Tags: tikz-pgf, adjustbox, marginnote

this is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{book}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x,utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[garamond]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a5paper, top=15mm, left=15mm, right=15mm, bottom=20mm, headsep=10mm, footskip=12mm}
\usepackage{adjustbox} 
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs} 
\usepackage[vlines]{tabularht}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\thickhline}{
    \noalign {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \hrule height 1pt
    \futurelet \reserved@a \@xhline
}
\makeatother

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % zentriert und gleichmäßig verteilt

\begin{document}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
\begin{adjustbox}{angle=90}
{\fontsize{8}{9}\selectfont
    \begin{tabularhtx}{\linewidth}{\textheight}{|Y|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|}
    \hline
        \interrowfill
       Wochen  & Kaffee & Rizinusöl & Mahlzeit & Leinöl & Acidol & Saft & Kalium & Lugol & Schilddr. & Niacin & Pankreatin & Leberextr. \\
    \interrowfill
    \thickhline
    \interrowfill
      2 -- 3   & 4 Std. &  2 Tage  & normal  & 2 TL  &  3 x 2  & 1 - 5 - 4 - 3 & 10 x 2 &  6 x 1 & 3 x 1/2 & 6 x 1  & 4 x 3  & täglich \\
    \interrowfill
    \hline
    \interrowfill
      3     &  &       &   &    &       &       &       &       &       &       &     &  \\
    \interrowfill
    \hline
    \interrowfill
      5     &  &       &    &   &       &       &       &       &       &       &     &  \\
    \interrowfill
    \hline
    \interrowfill
      4     &  &       &   &    &       &       &       &       &       &       &     &  \\
    \interrowfill
    \hline
    \interrowfill
      5     &  &       &    &   &       &       &       &       &       &       &     &  \\
    \interrowfill
    \hline
    \interrowfill
      4     &  &       &    &   &       &       &       &       &       &       &     &  \\
    \interrowfill
    \hline
    \interrowfill
      6     &  &       &    &   &       &       &       &       &       &       &     &  \\
    \interrowfill
    \hline
    \interrowfill
      6     &  &       &    &   &       &       &       &       &       &       &     &  \\
    \interrowfill
    \hline
    \interrowfill
      6    &  &       &     &  &       &       &       &       &       &       &     &  \\
    \interrowfill
    \hline
    \interrowfill
      9     &  &       &   &    &       &       &       &       &       &       &     &  \\
    \interrowfill
    \hline
    \interrowfill
      9    &  &       &    &   &       &       &       &       &       &       &     &  \\
    \interrowfill
    \hline
    \interrowfill
      7     &  &       &  &     &       &       &       &       &       &       &     &  \\
    \interrowfill
    \hline
    \end{tabularhtx}}
\end{adjustbox}

\end{document}
```

The tablecells have no space to add additional comments, so I'd like to add the comments to the margin like in this picture:

[image]

I tried to add a `tikzpicture` but when I add it before the `adjustbox` it's placed on the side before, after `adjustbox` on the next page.

Has anybody an idea?

Comment: Use either `utf8x` or `utf8`, not both. Preferably the latter (without `ucs`, of course).

Comment: I had some issues with some characters and had to use it that way but unfortunately can't remember why exactly.

Comment: No, you couldn't solve it that way: basically, `utf8` is ignored when you also have utf8x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option using TikZ with the `remember picture`, `overlay` options for a `tikzpicture` and `current page.east` to place the node containing the comment. Adjust the settings according to your particular needs (I don't have `mathdesign`, so I suppressed from my example; I also removed `utf8x` since `utf8` should be preferable):

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{book}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a5paper, top=15mm, left=15mm, right=15mm, bottom=20mm, headsep=10mm, footskip=12mm}
\usepackage{adjustbox} 
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs} 
\usepackage[vlines]{tabularht}
\usepackage{tikz} 

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\thickhline}{
    \noalign {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \hrule height 1pt
    \futurelet \reserved@a \@xhline
}
\makeatother

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % zentriert und gleichmäßig verteilt

\begin{document}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[
  rotate=90,
  rounded corners,
  draw=red,
  ultra thick,
  text width=2.5cm,
  align=center,
  minimum height=15pt
]
  at ([xshift=-12pt]current page.east)
  {comment};
\end{tikzpicture}%    
\begin{adjustbox}{angle=90}
{\fontsize{8}{9}\selectfont
    \begin{tabularhtx}{\linewidth}{\textheight}{|Y|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|}
    \hline
        \interrowfill
       Wochen  & Kaffee & Rizinusöl & Mahlzeit & Leinöl & Acidol & Saft & Kalium & Lugol & Schilddr. & Niacin & Pankreatin & Leberextr. \\
    \interrowfill
    \thickhline
    \interrowfill
      2 -- 3   & 4 Std. &  2 Tage  & normal  & 2 TL  &  3 x 2  & 1 - 5 - 4 - 3 & 10 x 2 &  6 x 1 & 3 x 1/2 & 6 x 1  & 4 x 3  & täglich \\
    \interrowfill
    \hline
    \interrowfill
      3     &  &       &   &    &       &       &       &       &       &       &     &  \\
    \interrowfill
    \hline
    \interrowfill
      5     &  &       &    &   &       &       &       &       &       &       &     &  \\
    \interrowfill
    \hline
    \interrowfill
      4     &  &       &   &    &       &       &       &       &       &       &     &  \\
    \interrowfill
    \hline
    \interrowfill
      5     &  &       &    &   &       &       &       &       &       &       &     &  \\
    \interrowfill
    \hline
    \interrowfill
      4     &  &       &    &   &       &       &       &       &       &       &     &  \\
    \interrowfill
    \hline
    \interrowfill
      6     &  &       &    &   &       &       &       &       &       &       &     &  \\
    \interrowfill
    \hline
    \interrowfill
      6     &  &       &    &   &       &       &       &       &       &       &     &  \\
    \interrowfill
    \hline
    \interrowfill
      6    &  &       &     &  &       &       &       &       &       &       &     &  \\
    \interrowfill
    \hline
    \interrowfill
      9     &  &       &   &    &       &       &       &       &       &       &     &  \\
    \interrowfill
    \hline
    \interrowfill
      9    &  &       &    &   &       &       &       &       &       &       &     &  \\
    \interrowfill
    \hline
    \interrowfill
      7     &  &       &  &     &       &       &       &       &       &       &     &  \\
    \interrowfill
    \hline
    \end{tabularhtx}}%
\end{adjustbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just end the table with

```
\interrowfill
\hline
\multicolumn{13}{c}{\rule{0pt}{4ex}* comment}
\end{tabularhtx}
```

The invisible rule provides for vertical separation. If you want the comment to start under a specific column, say the seventh, type

```
\interrowfill
\hline
\multicolumn{6}{c}{} &
\multicolumn{7}{l}{\rule{0pt}{4ex}* comment}
\end{tabularhtx}
```

Here's a picture with centering:

[image]